# Is it possible to undo right bits-hifting operation?

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

I have a piece of code where part of it does some bits-shifting manipulation.
One of the operations Its right shift by 8 bits. I need a function to get the original value after the manipulations, I tried few ways but with no success.
I know there are operations which are destructive  and cannot be undone because lost of bits.
Can 8 bit right-shifting be undone? If not, Is there other operator I can use the achieve the same result as the bit shifting but can be reversed?
My piece of code with an example (I used chrome console to simplify, My original code is also JS):

```
let x = 11297 >> 8
undefined
x
44
let y = x << 8
undefined
y
11264
```

Comment: shifting left always shifts in `0`s from the right - so - no - why would you want the code to "remember" the shifted out bits - if you want them, store them somewhere

Comment: I`m doing some operations on data and the exporting it into a bin file, And I need the option of importing that file later and extract the original data

Comment: shifting bits is lossy - why do you want to save the data with shifted bits